# NLTK, Naive Bayes: why are some features NONE?

Tags: python, nltk, naivebayes

I am trying to implement a Naive Bayes with NLTK.

When I print out the most informative features, some of them are assigned "NONE". Why is that?

I am using the bag of words model: When I output the features, every feature is assigned true.

Whare does the NONE come from?

I read that

```
The feature value 'None' is reserved for unseen feature values;
```

here: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html

What does that mean?

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
import nltk.data
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import collections
from nltk.classify.util import accuracy
import itertools
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures
import nltk.metrics

def bag_of_words(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

def bag_of_words_not_in_set(words, badwords):
    return bag_of_words(set(words) - set(badwords))

def bag_of_words_without_stopwords(words):
    badwords = stopwords.words("german")
    return bag_of_words_not_in_set(words, badwords)

def label_feats_from_corpus(corp, feature_detector=bag_of_words_without_stopwords):
    label_feats = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for label in corp.categories():
        for fileid in corp.fileids(categories=[label]):
            feats = feature_detector(corp.words(fileids=[fileid]))
            label_feats[label].append(feats)
    return label_feats

def split_label_feats(lfeats, split=0.75):
    train_feats = []
    test_feats = []
    for label, feats in lfeats.items():
        cutoff = int(len(feats) * split)
        train_feats.extend([(feat, label) for feat in feats[:cutoff]])
        test_feats.extend([(feat, label) for feat in feats[cutoff:]])
    return train_feats, test_feats


reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('D:/corpus/', r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+)/*')

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in reader.words())

def bigram_word_feats(words, score_fn=BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq, n=200):
    bigram_finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(words)
    bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(score_fn, n)
    return dict([(ngram, True) for ngram in itertools.chain(words, bigrams)])

bigrams = bigram_word_feats(reader.words());

lfeats = label_feats_from_corpus(reader)

train_feats, test_feats = split_label_feats(lfeats, split=0.75)
len(train_feats)
nb_classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_feats)


print("------------------------")
acc = accuracy(nb_classifier, test_feats)
print(acc)
print("------------------------")
feats = nb_classifier.most_informative_features(n=25)
for feat in feats:
    print(feat) # some are NONE

print("------------------------")
nb_classifier.show_most_informative_features(n=25) # some are NONE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the full docstring for the `NaiveBayesClassifier` class explains:

> If the classifier encounters an input with a feature that has
>       never been seen with any label, then rather than assigning a
>       probability of 0 to all labels, it will ignore that feature.
>
> The feature value 'None' is reserved for unseen feature values;
>       you generally should not use 'None' as a feature value for one of
>       your own features.

If your data contain a feature that was never associated with a label, the value of that feature will be `None`. Suppose you train a classifier with features `W`, `X`, and then classify something with features `W`, `X`, `Z`. The value `None` will be used for feature `Z` because that feature was never seen in training.

**Further Explanation:**

Seeing `None` does not surprise me because language data are sparse. In a corpus of movie reviews, there will be words that only appear in 1 or 2 documents. For example, an actor's name or word from the title might only appear in 1 review.

Removing frequent (stop) and infrequent words from a corpus prior to analysis is common. For their topic model of *Science*, [Blei and Lafferty (2007)](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/papers/BleiLafferty2007.pdf) write: *"The total vocabulary size in this collection is 375,144 terms. We trim the 356,195 terms that occurred fewer than 70 times as well as 296 stop words."*

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I still don't fully understand how this happens. Let's assume my corpus contains the word about. I use the bag of words model, so I assign this feature the value "True". The word about is in my corpus, it is not in my stopword list, when I output the features, I can see that each feature is assigned the value "true".  Can you spot any error in my code?I use 75% of my corpus for training and 25% for testing. The "none" means that in my testing portion there are words that have never been assigned a label?

Comment: I cannot see any errors in your code. Yes, my understanding is that `None` means there were words never encountered with a label during training. I updated my answer with some additional explanation.

Comment: Hm... still a little weird. Besides the stopword list, I don't do any trimming. Do you mean that the NB classifier of the NLTK does this trimming automatically?

Comment: You get `None` _because_ you don't do any trimming. The frequency of `None` values would decline if you trimmed the vocabulary; the NB classifier does not trim automatically. It is something you do prior to analysis in order to reduce the dimensionality of the feature space.

Comment: aah, now I get it. remove the infrequent words that would otherwise be assigned "None", right? (sorry, I am completelty new at this)

Comment: Exactly. Those features are not useful. Trim the vocabulary before building the classifier. The paper I linked to does a lot of trimming; you will need to experiment for your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time  and help!!